# Longtable Caption Error in Overleaf- Package ltCaption error: Not allowed in longtable* environment

Tags: errors, longtable

I'm trying to create a longtable in Latex and am using Overleaf as my tool. My table prints fine, except for the caption. I went through past solutions offered to similar questions and followed the same instruction, but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
\begin{longtable*}[h!]{|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
% \caption{Long table caption.\label{long}}\\
\caption{Theorem numbers, names, statements, and assumptions for theorems derived in paper \label{TheoremTable}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Theorem Number} & \textbf{Assumption Code} & \textbf{Theorem} & \textbf{Assumptions} \\
\hline
1 & Partition of Roles Within a Lifecycle Phase &   For any lifecycle phase \(l \in LPHASES\), the set \textit{ROLES} can be partitioned into \(AG_l\) and \(IG_l\). &  a \\
.
.
.
.
(Many more lines)
.
.
.
\hline

% \caption{Theorem numbers, names, statements, and assumptions for theorems derived in paper \label{TheoremTable}}\\

\end{longtable*}
```

I tried adding the caption both at the top and the bottom of the table, put the same error persists (Package ltCaption error: Not allowed in longtable* environment.). Upon compiling, I only see a new line added to my first two columns. Could somebody please help me with this and tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please provide a test file that produces the error so people can debug. You do not say what package you are using but the error you show is not a longtable package error message.

Comment: longtable (and presumably `longtable*` although the longtable package does not define an environment of that name) does not have a `[h!]` option.

Comment: From the `ltcaption` documentation: "Another bonus feature is the addition of the environment `longtable*` which does not increment the table counter.  (As a consequence, `\caption` is not available for such longtables, but `\caption*` still is.)" So either use `longtable` instead of `longtable*`, or use `\caption*` instead of `\caption`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the * after longtable and used only \caption and it worked. What a rookie mistake!